# Get last updated dict message from list of dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to get the latest update message to an entity from a data stream. Data comes as a list of dicts where each dict is an update message to the entity. I need only the latest update to the entity. My input comes as a list of dicts and the output needs to be in a dict of dicts

Notes: Only length gets updated, category stays static. I know which one is the latest update because, for that entity, it will have the latest timestamp

Data comes like this:

```
[{u'length': u'1',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityA',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422690'},
 {u'length': u'1.1',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityA',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422691'},
 {u'length': u'1.2',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityA',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422692'},
 {u'length': u'0.9',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityB',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422689'},
 {u'length': u'0.9',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityB',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422690'}]
```

I need to manipulate this so I only get:

```
{u'entityA':{u'length': u'1.2', 
             u'category': u'3', 
             u'entity': u'entityA', 
             u'timestamp': u'1562422692'},
 u'entityB':{u'length': u'0.9', 
             u'category': u'3', 
             u'entity': u'entityB', 
             u'timestamp': u'1562422690'}}
```

I am new to python - I knew I could achieve this in SQL with:

```
select * from
(select
   length, 
   category, 
   entity, 
   timestamp, 
   row_number () over (partition by entity order by timestamp desc) as rnumb
from data
)foo
where rnumb = 1
```

but I am doing this in python and it seems like too much of a workaround to go through SQL within python, unfortunately my upstream data SQL does not support row_number()

Updating this question after I tried both Gillespie and Alexander's approaches. Gillespie's approach does not seem to work, Alexander's does work but becomes very slow when dealing with a lot of data - any speedier alternative?

```
test_data = [
{u'length': u'0',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityA',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422690'},
{u'length': u'1',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityA',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422680'},
{u'length': u'2',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityB',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422691'},
{u'length': u'3',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityB',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422688'},
{u'length': u'4',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityC',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422630'},
{u'length': u'5',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityC',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422645'}
]
```

```
>>> test_gillespie = max(test_data, lambda x: x["timestamp"])
test_gillespie
```

```
[{u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityA',
  u'length': u'0',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422690'},
 {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityA',
  u'length': u'1',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422680'},
 {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityB',
  u'length': u'2',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422691'},
 {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityB',
  u'length': u'3',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422688'},
 {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityC',
  u'length': u'4',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422630'},
 {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityC',
  u'length': u'5',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422645'}]
```

```
>>>test_alexander = {entity: sorted([d for d in test_data if d.get('entity') == entity], key=lambda x: x['timestamp'])[-1]
     for entity in set(d.get('entity') for d in test_data)}
test_alexander
```

```
{u'entityA': {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityA',
  u'length': u'0',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422690'},
 u'entityB': {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityB',
  u'length': u'2',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422691'},
 u'entityC': {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityC',
  u'length': u'5',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422645'}}
```

Comment: Seems like you could do something like `max(my_dict.values(), lambda x: x["timestamp"])`

Comment: @Gillespie will try right now and post the results

Comment: @Gillespie thank you for providing this pointer - I didn't get to try it because .values() does not work with a list, I would have had to change my list of dicts to a dict of dicts...

Comment: Well in that case you would just do `max(my_list, lambda x: x["timestamp"])`

Comment: @Gillespie please see my recent update to the question - I can't get your method to work but I need something faster than Alexander's

Comment: It's because everything is a string - you'll need to map it to an integer first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is assigned to a variable called `data`, you can use a dictionary comprehension together with `sorted`.  For each entity (`set(d.get('entity') for d in data)` creates a set of all unique entities), sort its data based on the timestamp and then take the last item (i.e. the most recent) via the `[-1]` index selection.

```
>>> {entity: sorted([d for d in data if d.get('entity') == entity], key=lambda x: x['timestamp'])[-1]
     for entity in set(d.get('entity') for d in data)}
{'entityA': {'length': '1.2',
  'category': '3',
  'entity': 'entityA',
  'timestamp': '1562422692'},
 'entityB': {'length': '0.9',
  'category': '3',
  'entity': 'entityB',
  'timestamp': '1562422690'}}
```

A faster method would involve using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values('timestamp')
result = df.groupby('entity', as_index=False).last()
>>> result
    entity category length   timestamp
0  entityA        3    1.2  1562422692
1  entityB        3    0.9  1562422690

>>> result.to_dict('r')
[{'entity': 'entityA',
  'category': '3',
  'length': '1.2',
  'timestamp': '1562422692'},
 {'entity': 'entityB',
  'category': '3',
  'length': '0.9',
  'timestamp': '1562422690'}]
```

​

Comment: Slack? Or Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Alexander is there a quicker alternative to this method? It takes a long time when working with ~7k unique entities (which could be as many as 7mil messages in the upstream, supposing that each entry got updated 100 times)

Answer (score 0):

I better framed my follow-up question regarding performance in a new question, if you have a similar problem check it:
[Is there a faster alternative to this approach to get last update message from list of dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923134/is-there-a-faster-alternative-to-this-approach-to-get-last-update-message-from-l)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
test_data = [
{u'length': u'0',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityA',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422690'},
{u'length': u'1',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityA',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422680'},
{u'length': u'2',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityB',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422691'},
{u'length': u'3',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityB',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422688'},
{u'length': u'4',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityC',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422630'},
{u'length': u'5',
  u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityC',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422645'}
]

test_gillespie = max(test_data, key=lambda x: int(x["timestamp"]))

print(test_gillespie)
```

Output:

```
{'length': '2', 'category': '3', 'entity': 'entityB', 'timestamp': '1562422691'}
```

See: https://repl.it/repls/StimulatingLightcoralBotany