# Is there a faster alternative to this approach to get last update message from list of dict?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, performance, dictionary

I need to get the last update message from a data stream. Data comes like this:

```
test_data = 
[{u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityA',
  u'length': u'0',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422690'},
 {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityA',
  u'length': u'1',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422680'},
 {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityB',
  u'length': u'2',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422691'},
 {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityB',
  u'length': u'3',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422688'},
 {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityC',
  u'length': u'4',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422630'},
 {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityC',
  u'length': u'5',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422645'},
 {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityD',
  u'length': u'6',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422645'}]
```

The following approach was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916467/get-last-updated-dict-message-from-list-of-dict)

```
test_alexander = {entity: sorted([d for d in test_data if d.get('entity') == entity], key=lambda x: x['timestamp'])[-1]
     for entity in set(d.get('entity') for d in test_data)}
```

which returns this (it works exactly as intended):

```
{u'entityA': {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityA',
  u'length': u'0',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422690'},
 u'entityB': {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityB',
  u'length': u'2',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422691'},
 u'entityC': {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityC',
  u'length': u'5',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422645'},
 u'entityD': {u'category': u'3',
  u'entity': u'entityD',
  u'length': u'6',
  u'timestamp': u'1562422645'}}
```

The problem is that I have 7k unique "entities", and as many as 7mil list items in "test_data". The above solution takes ages and I am wondering if there is a faster approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this as a single loop with a single comparison. Just keep track of the max seen so far for each category as you proceed through the loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def getMax(test_data):
    d = defaultdict(lambda: {'timestamp':0})

    for item in test_data:
        if int(item['timestamp']) > int(d[item['entity']]['timestamp']):
            d[item['entity']] = item
    return d
```

The return value will be a dictionary keyed to the `entity` with the max value for each. It should be significantly faster that sorting or building arrays in the loop. Still 7mil takes a while.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Meyer - how can I modify your answer to get an output which is exactly like the last block of code in my question?

Comment: @MV the defaultdictionary is just a dictionary with a little extra stuff. You can use it as a dictionary. If you want a plain dictionary just pass it to `dict()` -- `dict(getMax(test_data))` or similar. Or `return dict(d)` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

seems like pure-python solutions might be too slow for your needs, I'd suggest using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html), which may perform much better.

can you try this?

```py
import pandas as pd

test_data = [{u'category': u'3',
              u'entity': u'entityA',
              u'length': u'0',
              u'timestamp': u'1562422690'},
             {u'category': u'3',
              u'entity': u'entityA',
              u'length': u'1',
              u'timestamp': u'1562422680'},
             {u'category': u'3',
              u'entity': u'entityB',
              u'length': u'2',
              u'timestamp': u'1562422691'},
             {u'category': u'3',
              u'entity': u'entityB',
              u'length': u'3',
              u'timestamp': u'1562422688'},
             {u'category': u'3',
              u'entity': u'entityC',
              u'length': u'4',
              u'timestamp': u'1562422630'},
             {u'category': u'3',
              u'entity': u'entityC',
              u'length': u'5',
              u'timestamp': u'1562422645'},
             {u'category': u'3',
              u'entity': u'entityD',
              u'length': u'6',
              u'timestamp': u'1562422645'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
df["timestamp"] = df["timestamp"].astype(int)

print(df.loc[df.groupby("entity")["timestamp"].idxmax()].to_dict(orient='records'))
```

Comment: Thank you @Adam.Er8 for taking the time to go through my problem and providing an answer. I was successful by using the defaultdict approach mentioned by others.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `max` instead of `sorted`, because you only need the maximum entry and not to sort the rest of the item:

```py
test_alexander = {entity: max([d for d in test_data if d.get('entity') == entity], key=lambda x: x['timestamp'])
                  for entity in set(d.get('entity') for d in test_data)}
```

(max will take O(n) and sorting will take O(n*logn))

Comment: still took ages (about 6 mins) - I am starting to think the problem is with the second line ("for entity in...") rather than in the max vs sort

Comment: @MV I will post a different answer recommending to use pandas, which might be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by partitioning by entity and then use max to take the newest record for each entity. This would have linear complexity. The code you have filters and then sorts the records for each entity that is near cubic.

In Python this would look like:

```
partitions = dict()
for record in test_data:
    partitions.setdefault(record['entity'], []).append(record)
# replace this with defaultdict for 2x performance 

for key in partitions:
    partitions[key] = max(partitions[key], key=lambda x: int(x['timestamp']))
```

The result is in `partitions`. And has shape `{entity:[{}]}`.

The memory usage of this can be reduced by replacing the accumulation with a max call but that might actually be slower.

Comment: your answer throws `KeyError: u'entityA' ` any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, missed putting the subscript in the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. It scans through the test data once and records the latest message for each entity:

```
from collections import defaultdict

latest_message = defaultdict(lambda: dict('timestamp'=0)

for data in test_data:
    latest = latest_message[data[entity]]
    if data['timestamp'] > latest['timestamp']:
        latest_message[data[entity]].update(data)
```